# Full-screen video playback on Android tablets

Tags: android, tablet, android-fullscreen

I always knew, that true full-screen mode on Android tablets was impossible to achieve without rooting your device, but recently I acquired 4.3-based Nexus 7 2013 and I can clearly see YouTube and VLC hiding menu bar.

I won't pollute this question with code for obvious attempts of making my Activity full-screen programaticaly or via `AndroidManifest.xml` and simply ask, if anyone has idea of going full-screen on Android 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ICS, system navigation bar can be temporarily hidden using [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) flag.

In your activity:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```